# System of generators for $\Bbb Z_9\times \Bbb Z_{18}$.

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, finite-groups, finitely-generated

Is $\{(4,3),(3,5)\}$ a system of generators for $\Bbb Z_9\times \Bbb Z_{18}$?

I tried to generate the elements using the straightforward method $(4,3), (8,6), (3, 9)$ ... but it takes too long.

Can I use a faster method?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v_1=(4,3)$ and $v_2=(3,5)$. Then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}4&3\\3&5\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\e_2\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$.
The matrix has determinant $11$, which is invertible in the ring $\Bbb Z_9\times \Bbb Z_{18}$. Therefore, $v_1$ and $v_2$ generate the same additive group as $e_1$ and $e_2$.

Explicitly,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\e_2\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}7&3\\3&2\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: See also [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B4%2C3%5D%2C%5B3%2C5%5D%5D+%5B%5B7%2C3%5D%2C%5B3%2C2%5D%5D)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$\gcd(4,9)=\gcd(5,18)=1.$$

Comment: I took an example like <2,3> for Z4 x Z4 and it work but I don't know why exactly. Furthermore, (4,9) and (5,18) aren't the generators, rather the products of the generator, and prime between them, so I don't quite understand.

Comment: It should not have worked, @GeorgeB, since $\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_4$ is not cyclic. As for my hint: since $\gcd(4,9)=1$, the order of $4$ in $\Bbb Z_9$ is $9$; similarly, that of $5$ in $\Bbb Z_{18}$ is $18$; and since multiplication is commutative, $a=(4,3)$ and $b=(3,5)$ commute. Thus $a$ and $b$ generate $\Bbb Z_9\times\Bbb Z_{18}$ since $3\mid 9$ and $3\mid 18$.

Answer (score 3):

The *Smith normal form* can be used here: $\begin{pmatrix}4&3\\3&5\\9&0\\0&18\end{pmatrix}\to\begin{pmatrix}4&3\\11&11\\9&0\\0&18\end{pmatrix}\to\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Thus the elements do generate.